# Having trouble using the method Array.IndexOf()

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and I'm trying to find the index of a particular array using the `Array.IndexOf()` but it's always returning the index as **-1** .Is there something wrong with my code?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] a = new string[]{ "a","b","c","d" };
            int index = Array.IndexOf(a, "2");
            Console.WriteLine(index);
            Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I think you're slightly confused about what `Array.IndexOf` does, and how. You're searching for the string `"2"` in an array containing the strings `"a", "b", "c", "d"`, what did you expect it to return? Can you elaborate on your expectations here? -1 means "not found". Try searching for `"b"`, then you should get back to `1`.

Comment: To answer your question, no, nothing seems wrong with your code. I think you expected it to do something else though so in that regard there might be something wrong.

Comment: I'm guessing you probably just want `a[1]` <-- return the second element of the array`

Comment: index of -1 means it does not exist because "2" is not in your array, if you searched for "b" it would return 1

Comment: I got the output now I was trying to give the index as a parameter instead of the string, my mistake. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

No, there is nothing wrong with your code if you know what you are doing.

`Array.IndexOf(Array,Object)`

> Searches for the specified object and returns the index of its first occurrence in a one-dimensional array.

You are trying to search `"2"` in the array which contains the elements `"a","b","c","d"`. Since it can't be found you get `-1`.

Search for something like `"c"`

```
int index = Array.IndexOf(a, "c"); // You will get 2 (which is the index)
```